# Sorting numbers in a JTable

Tags: java, swing

How do I realize sorting of columns containing only numbers in a JTable? There is the class `TableRowSorter`. Using this, however, leads to the following: for every number the string representation is taken by invoking toString and then this is compared instead. What I receive is for instance this:

100, 13, 2, 22, 9
instead 2, 9, 13, 22, 100

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

To avoid this, there is the following method:

```
sorter.setComparator(column,comparator);
```

Since my numbers are only Integer, Long and Double, I don't see why I should define a humble Comparator of standard java.lang classes. Is there an easier way?

Comment: What class your model  returns for getColumnClass()? Is it integer or string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define Number for the column's class.

See TableModel

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Now the numbers are also represented in more natural way for the eye.

Answer (score 2):

How is your table model defined? If the `getColumnClass` method return `Integer.class` (or `Long.class`, or `Number.class`, depending on what the column contains), then the sort should be right, and you shouldn't have to configure any specific row sorter.